# Adding pointers to an established pointer array after using strtok

Tags: c, arrays, strtok, strcpy

I'm trying to do the following actions in my code, which is an implementation of textsort in C.

-the data[] contains pointers to sentences read in from a file.

- make a copy of jth content of the "data" array and store it in the line buffer char *. (This array is an array of pointers instantiated as a const char **data and malloc-ed in the following way: data = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numlines))
- I am then trying to strtok the sentences into words using a whitespace as a deliminator.

-Lastly, I'm trying to store the pointers returned by strtok in an array of pointers initialized as char *tokenarray and malloc-ed as tokenarray = malloc(sizeof(char *)*numlines)). Here is the code:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define MAXCHAR 150 
#define COPYMAX 150 

char inpstr[MAXCHAR];  //char array for the input string storage 
char copyd[MAXCHAR];   // copy needed for some fxn 
char *temp_bffr; 
size_t buffsize; 
int status;
char filename; 
int numlines; 
numlines = 5; 
int i; 
char *storedline;
FILE *fileo; //fopen pointer
const char **data; 



int separate_words(char ** txtarray){
    printf("separating\n"); 
    char *token; //for strtok
    char *tokenarray; 
    int j; 
    char *linebuffer = (char *) malloc(MAXCHAR); //malloc since we want to modify this copy? 
    tokenarray = malloc(sizeof(char *)*numlines); 

    for(j = 0; j<= numlines; j++){
        //printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, data[j]); 
        strcpy(linebuffer, data[j]); 
        token = strtok(linebuffer, " "); 
        tokenarray[j] = token; 
    }
    return 0; 
}


int my_compare(const void *elem1, const void *elem2){

    printf("comparing is hard"); 
    //qsort????


    return 0; 
}


int main(){

    fileo = fopen("short_alma.txt","r"); 
    data = (char **)malloc(numlines * sizeof(char *));
    //check stats from file 
    struct stat buffer; 
    if(fstat(status, &buffer) != 0){
    printf("error: fstat()\n");
        exit(1); 
    }
    // temporary buffer 
    temp_bffr = malloc(sizeof(char)* (MAXCHAR +1)); 
    i = 0; 
    //usefgets to start reading: 
    while(fgets(temp_bffr, MAXCHAR, fileo)){
        //printf("temp_bffr is : \n"); 
        //puts(temp_bffr); 
        //check sizeif line < MAX, save size and do realloc()
        if(strlen(temp_bffr) < MAXCHAR){
            buffsize = strlen(temp_bffr);  
            //malloc memory using buffer size before the string copy??? is this it??? 
            data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*numlines);    
            strcpy(data[i], temp_bffr);
            i++;            
        }

        else{
            printf("line has too many chars!"); 
        }
    }
        separate_words(data); //separate the strings in our array


    //return data; 
    return 0; 

}
```

`

Comment: Your 1st call to `strtok` is `token = strtok(linebuffer, " ");` all remaining calls must be `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` (I would also use `" \n"`)

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll try it out